# Change createMaterialTopTabNavigator active style

Tags: css, react-native

I am using react native and currently have this css code for the navigator function code

```
<Tabs.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    tabBarScrollEnabled: true,
                    tabBarShowLabel: false,
                    tabBarActiveTintColor: 'green',
                    tabBarStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor,
                        position: 'absolute',
                        bottom: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        margin: 50,
                        maxHeight: 50,
                        borderRadius: 10,
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        ...style.shadow
                    }
                }}
            >
```

How do I style the active blue bar selector. I would ideally just want to change the color. What is the best way to go about this. I have tried using `tabBarActiveTintColor` with no luck.
[What I want styled](https://reactnavigation.org/assets/navigators/tabs/material-top-tabs.mov)

Comment: try using this tabBarOptions={{ indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor } }} in <Tabs.Navigator>, not in screenOptions. It might help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `tabBarIndicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: 'green' },` to change bar color in version 6 :)

Answer (score 0):

please do this

`tabBarOptions={{ tabBarActiveTintColor:'blue' }}`

It helps you lots.

Comment: ```tabBarOptions``` is deprecated and when i use ```tabBarActiveTintColor```in screen options this does not work